# Rounding in the method of least squares for linear regression analysis?

Tags: statistics, mathematical-physics, least-squares, regression-analysis

I tend to round off the intermediate values (like that for $\Sigma x^2) $ of my calculation for slope, etc., to appropriate significant digits by considering the significance of the raw data.
Sometimes I get the wrong answer because of this.

My question: Am I wrong for rounding off, or is the exercise book wrong?

Just to clarify: this is for physics data.

Comment: This is very easy to check: just don't do the rounding and compare. One can contruct examples where rounding in the intermediate result gives disastarous results, but this is not expected in general. For example if $a=1.02$ and $b=101$ then $\frac{a}{100a-b} = 1.01$ but if we round $a=1.0$ then we get $-1$. You should try to not round untill you get to the final answer to avoid any possibillity of this happening.

Comment: I agree with @Winther that rounding off is not a good idea in th regression analysis. The effect of that will depend on how much correlation between the dependent varable and regressors you have in your data. But potentially such rounding off could lead to severe distortions in your estimate.